# Change values in codeigniter query result object

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to do something like :

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT date, foo, bar, baz FROM table;");
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
    $row->date = unix_to_human($row->date, TRUE, 'eu');
}
$this->dbutil->csv_from_result($query);
```

When I export the csv file, the date has not been modified.
I've tried referencing the row variable ( &$row )but it did not work either.

Any ideas ?

Comment: You are modifying date in loop , but passing ``$query`` to csv ..

Comment: Do you mean that modifying date does not modify $query ?

Comment: Yes, either convert the date in query itself or assign ``$row`` to an array after modifying date then pass the array to CSV.

Comment: I tried first to modify the date in the query, but did not succeed. That's why I'm trying to modify the result. I can't convert the result to a pure array, as csv_from_result requires a valid query object...

Comment: Try this 
``$query = $this->db->query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, "%d/%l/%Y") as date, foo, bar, baz FROM table;");
  $res = $query->result();
   $this->dbutil->csv_from_result($res);`` .  Change the date format like you want.

Comment: The double quotes break the query string. If I turn them to ' or ` the date is empty in the results... Spent hours on this yesterday and could not find a workaround.

Comment: I switched DATE_FORMAT to "FROM_UNIXTIME (date) as `date` and it works like charm

Comment: You can iterate elements by reference. [Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).